# Normalizing data in R

Tags: r

Hello I have the following data.frame (appended). I would like to add an additional column with normalized counts `N = N/sum(N)`. I had a previous data.frame without the date column and was able to do this using

`oo[, N.norm := N/sum(N), by=Operator]`

I have tried to add Date to the by function

```
oo[, N.norm := N/sum(N), by=Operator,Date]
```

but receive an error message

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(oo, , `:=`(N.norm, N/sum(N)), by = Operator, Date) : 
  unused argument(s) (by = Operator)
```

For example for operator 'A' in Month 'Jan 2013', I have the number of counts `N` of each `ROI_SCore` = c("Good","OK","Poor","Crap"). I would like to sum N for that combination (A and Jan 2013) and divide the counts `N` by `sum(N)`

On another note, can anyone provide me with a decent introduction to manipulating data.frames in R

```
structure(list(Operator = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("A", 
"D", "J", "L", "M"), class = "factor"), ROI_Score = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Crap", "Good", "OK", "Poor"), class = "factor"), 
    Date = c("Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013", "Apr 2013", "Feb 2013", "Jan 2013", "Mar 2013", 
    "May 2013"), N = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 15, 1, 5, 3, 2, 3, 
    1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 14, 17, 16, 8, 7, 5, 
    10, 6, 1, 5, 24, 27, 31, 16, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26, 24, 20, 
    11, 18, 3, 4, 17, 3, 2, 20, 36, 12, 21, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    3, 12, 5, 12, 4, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 29, 37, 41, 25, 10, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 15, 17, 3, 6, 4, 5, 4, 1, 14, 13, 9, 15, 9
    )), .Names = c("Operator", "ROI_Score", "Date", "N"), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

I am uncertain if the data is in data.frame or data.table format. Here is my code, adapted from a solution given by Arun ([reshape/remould data frame to create normalized bar chart and pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610185/reshape-remould-data-frame-to-create-normalized-bar-chart-and-pie-chart))

```
df <- data.frame(read.csv("/misc/jaguar_data/report/system/db_fs/roi_scores.csv"))
#Get date into nice structure for faceting
df$Date = strftime(strptime(df$Date,f="%d/%m/%Y"), "%b %Y")
dt <- data.table(df)
ops <- as.character(unique(dt$Operator))
scr <- as.character(unique(dt$ROI_Score))
dts <- unique(dt$Date)

oo <- setkey(dt[, .N, by="Operator,ROI_Score,Date"], Operator,
ROI_Score,Date)[CJ(ops, scr,dts)][is.na(N), N:= 0L]

oo[, N.norm := N/sum(N), by=Operator]
```

Comment: This additional column: N.norm for row i should be N[i]/sum(N[1...i), but aggregated by both Operator and Date?  Do you really mean `data.table` and not `data.frame`?  The `:=` operator is restricted to `data.table`.  Please clarify which structure you are working with: you gave us a data frame.

Comment: @BryanHanson - I am uncertain. I have updated my question to explain how I arrived with the data structure oo. It was a data.frame initially but I think it is now a data.table

Comment: You are definitely using a `data.table`, see your own code which makes this clear (you started with a `data.frame` but turned it into a `data.table`).  Usually these are used when the data set is very large and speed is critical.  Otherwise, a `data.frame` is usually fine.  What is it that you are trying to compute?

Comment: Looks like if you group by Operator, ROI_Score and Date every value is unique so there is only one of each possible combination.  Perhaps this is a feature of your test data and your real data is not this way?

Comment: @BryanHanson I am trying to compute for each operator and month (Jan 2013 etc). The percentages of Good, OK, Poor and Crap (appologies) analyses carrried out by operators. I will facet the results by month to look at general trends on a month by month basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code was (*almost*) perfect.  Two slight issues.

1:  You are using `data.table` syntax, so instead of `oo` being a `data.frame` it should be a `data.table`.  Simply use:

```
 library(data.table)  
 oo <- data.table(oo)
```

2:  When using `by` with more than one column, make sure to wrap the columns in `list(..)` or in as one single comma-separated string. Examples

```
 oo[, N.norm := N/sum(N), by=list(Operator,Date)]

 # - or - #
 oo[, N.norm := N/sum(N), by="Operator,Date"]
```

#### Edit: If you are hoping to divide by each total for each `Operator`-`Date` group, then your code should be as above.  If instead, you want to divide by the total of the *entire* data, then use

```
 oo[, N.norm := N/sum(DT$N), by=list(Operator,Date)]
```

---

Fixing those two things and using everything else exactly as you have it:

```
     Operator ROI_Score     Date  N    N.norm
  1:        A      Crap Apr 2013  0 0.0000000
  2:        A      Crap Feb 2013  0 0.0000000
  3:        A      Crap Jan 2013  0 0.0000000
  4:        A      Crap Mar 2013  0 0.0000000
  5:        A      Crap May 2013  0 0.0000000
 ---                                         
 96:        M      Poor Apr 2013 14 0.4827586
 97:        M      Poor Feb 2013 13 0.5000000
 98:        M      Poor Jan 2013  9 0.3103448
 99:        M      Poor Mar 2013 15 0.4166667
100:        M      Poor May 2013  9 0.6923077
```

---

### Edit 2:

Just a note.  In general, if you are using expressions within the `[`brackets`]`, especially the assign-by-reference operator `:=`, then your object should be a `data.table`.

If you see an error such as

```
 Error in `[.data.frame`( _<your object name>_, ...
```

then this is likely due to the fact that either (a) your object is not a data.table or (b) you forgot to load the data.table `package`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew it must have been a simple hack from the code I already had

Comment: @moadeep, no problem.  Please see the edited note at the bottom of the answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do what you want with this data set.  Here's why:

```
install.packages("plyr")
library("plyr")
str(tmp) # this is your data
count(tmp, vars = c("Operator", "ROI_Score"))
```

Gives this:

```
   Operator ROI_Score freq
1         A      Crap    5
2         A      Good    5
3         A        OK    5
4         A      Poor    5
5         D      Crap    5
6         D      Good    5
7         D        OK    5
8         D      Poor    5
9         J      Crap    5
10        J      Good    5
11        J        OK    5
12        J      Poor    5
13        L      Crap    5
14        L      Good    5
15        L        OK    5
16        L      Poor    5
17        M      Crap    5
18        M      Good    5
19        M        OK    5
20        M      Poor    5
```

And including `Date` makes every value unique, so all have a count of 1.

Using a `data.frame`, what you want can be in principle obtained by:

```
ans <- aggregate(N ~ Operator + ROI_Score + Date, data = tmp, FUN = sum)
```

And then change the function to do exactly what you want (divide by 100, the number of entries?).  But I'm not sure this is what you want.

EDIT

Since you want the percentages of each rating category by Operator and Date, I'd subset first then aggregate:

```
tmp2 <- subset(tmp, Operator == "A")
ans2 <- aggregate(N ~ ROI_Score, data = tmp2, FUN = sum)
ans2$N.norm <- ans2$N/sum(ans2$N)
```

Gives:

```
  ROI_Score  N    N.norm
1      Crap  0 0.0000000
2      Good 24 0.5106383
3        OK  9 0.1914894
4      Poor 14 0.2978723
```

Comment: Its not quite what I need but I appreciate your help. In the above example for each operator and month there are 4 possible scores. If the frequency is each 5. Then the sum would equal 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 20. And the percentage score for that operator and month would be Crap: 25%, Poor: 25%, OK: 25%, Good: 25%

Comment: No problem. I guess you need to add in Date to get exactly what you want: `N~ROI_Score + Date` Have fun.